# How to create xrdp external connection in Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: networking, server, 17.04, remote-desktop, xrdp

I followed this steps:

1. `sudo apt-get -y install xrdp`
2. `xrdp -v` (0.9.1)
3. deleted last two rows in a `/etc/xrdp/startwm.sh` and added `lxsession -s Lubuntu -e LXDE`
4. tried connect to - "ip:3389" (from Virual Machine (WinXP)) - doesn't connect. Tried to connect from Remmina Remote Desktop Client "ip:3389" - doesn't work.

I have installed vncserver and it works perfect, but still want to try xrdp.

my startwm.sh file - http://textuploader.com/dozid

my xrdp.ini file - http://textuploader.com/dozis

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here...

as described in this post; (see http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=10887) may be there is a configuration change in Lubuntu.  You might need to check that you are allowed to perform remote connections....

To check this, edit your **/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config** and check the line **allowed_users=**

if the file contains

- allowed_users=console;

try to update the file and make the line look like

- **allowed_users=anybody**

and try to connect using xRDP again

Try also first to modify the.. .xsession file instead of startwm.sh

Hope this help 
Till next time